# How to use does not equal to condition with wild card in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

if cells(3,3) value does not start with 7 or 3 then it pop up a message box with some message.

I am trying with this code but in every condition, it is pop up message.

```
ElseIf Cells(3, 3) <> 7 & "*" _
       Or Cells(3, 3) <> 3 & "*" Then
        MsgBox "Enter only 7 or 3 series OHR ID"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or to be really compact

```
ElseIf Not Cells(3, 3).Text Like "[37]*" Then
```

Comment: This is really a great solution, can you please explain to me how it is working. I am not understanding this "[37]* .

Comment: The square brackets indicate that either of the characters can match.  Take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/like-operator for more details.  `Like` is not as powerful as regular expressions but can do some basic matching well.

Answer (score 4):

```
ElseIf Not Left(Cells(3, 3), 1) = "7" _
        Or Left(Cells(3, 3), 1) = "3" Then
            MsgBox "Enter only 7 or 3 series OHR ID"
```

Comment: it is throwing a compile error: Expected: expression

Answer (score 1):

You may use the `Like` operator:

```
ElseIf Not CStr(Cells(3, 3).Value) Like "7*" Or _
       Not CStr(Cells(3, 3).Value) Like "3*" Then
```

Answer (score 0):

Function Left might help:

```
ElseIf Left(Cells(3, 3).Value, 1) <> "7" And Left(Cells(3, 3).Value, 1) <> "3" Then
        MsgBox "Enter only 7 or 3 series OHR ID"
```